# Multiple v-for to get values from Nested JSON array in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, html, api, vue.js

I am fetching data from external API and populating Table to display the JSON Data. The JSON data has multiple nested arrays, actually the data is for "Orders".
So I am trying to get the Items of the order in a cell, for that I am using "v-if" but i could not archive this.
The results I am getting for the below code is each item of the order in separate column, but i am trying to view the items in one cell and other 'meta_data'

Below is JSON data structure

```js
"line_items": [{
    "name": "Salat",
    "meta_data": [{
        "id": 11500,
        "key": "size",
        "value": "full"
      },
      {
        "id": 1150001,
        "key": "Dressing",
        "value": "green"
      }
    ],
    "price": 4.28571399999999957941554384888149797916412353515625
  },
  {
    "name": "Chicken",
    "meta_data": [{
        "id": 115111112,
        "key": "size",
        "value": "Normal (7,00 &#8364;)"
      },
      {
        "id": 1151111113,
        "key": "Extra sauce",
        "value": "Bbq(0,50 &#8364;)"
      }
    ],
    "price": 7.14285700000000023379698177450336515903472900390625
  },
]
```

This is how I am creating the table

```html
<table class="table table-bordered" id="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Order Id</th>
      <th scope="col">Name</th>
      <th scope="col">Items</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr 
      v-for="(order, index) in orders"
      :key="order.id"
      :class="{highlight: !order.is_printed}"
    >
      <td>{{ order.id }}</td>
      <td>{{ order.billing.first_name + " " +order.billing.last_name }}</td>
      <!-- <td>{{ order.line_items[].name}} </td>-->
      <td v-for="(items, index) in order.line_items">{{items.name}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

How can i archive this to get the names and meta data of the items of the order in one cell.

Suggestions will be great help.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By having the `v-for` on the `<td>` element in the template it means you will have a `<td>` created *for each* item in your `order.line_items` array. To have all of these items render within a single `<td>` cell, you need to put the v-for *inside* the `<td>`. An unordered list (`<ul>`) may be an appropriate HTML element to use. For example:

```
<td>
    <ul>
        <li v-for="(items, index) in order.line_items">{{items.name}}</li>
    </ul>
</td>
```

I have created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/76484/Lwv7buhf/) for your reference.

Comment: Yeah, it worked. Thanks for the answer. One question, can i use this same to get the "key and value" for each item from "meta_data" array. I am not getting it when using "order.line_items.meta_data".

Comment: @Tom: As `meta_data` is an Array, you would need to access each element within that array by its index, (ex., `order.line_items[0].meta_data[0]`). Alternatively, you could nest another `v-for` within your `line_items` `v-for`. See this forked fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/76484/xLpzomkb/

Comment: Thanks for it, i figured out. I am trying to access each element as you said for particular category product has three different eExtras, for that product I need not pich the index[1] in that array, need only [2] and [3], I am using this code `<li v-for="meta in items.meta_data" v-if = "meta.meta_data[2]">{{meta[1].value + meta[2].value}}</li>
                           <li v-else >{{meta.value}}</li>`, sorry to continue with this. I hope it will be easy one for your point the error. Thank you

Comment: @Tom: It's not quite clear to me what you are trying to do achieve. Perhaps it would be best to post a new question with more detail.

Comment: For example, pizza has 3 meta_data, other things may have 1 or 2 meta_data. For pizza , i do not want to display meta_data[0], only need meta_data[1] and meta_data[2]. This is what i am trying

Comment: Adding very specific conditions to your template sounds like a bad idea. For example, will Pizza be the only item for which you want to exclude the first meta_data item? We don't have space here to get into what the best approach would be. Here is an example with a filter method: https://jsfiddle.net/76484/9nk2fxq1/

Comment: For only 3 categories, i need to avoid meta_data[0].

Comment: Acyually , I am trying to print a bill for an order, so that is why i need to extract info from the JSON array, this is what I am trying to archive.